# Get ARM template for a specific API in Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

In the Azure API portal there is the Automation script tab, but that generates the ARM template for the entire resource group. It also includes a lot of other stuff that needed.

Is there a (simple) way to get hold of the ARM template for a specific API rather than the entire resource group? Can it be done through Azure cli? the REST API?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use the [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com) to locate your resource, the Uri at the top of the page will provide you a link to the template (requires authentication if you want to call it from outside of Resource Explorer).

[image: Azure Resource Explorer]

I also always refer back to [the reference documentation on ARM templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/), it is a very good place to start from. Whilst it doesn't give you your exact template, it does give you a very clear base to start from (example below). I find this far more productive that trying to read the templates in the Automation Script" section of the portal.

Good luck.

[image: Azure documentation for a CosmosDB resource]

Comment: Yeah that is much better way, the automation script approach is too slow as well. Especially in an IE browser.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that. there is only 1 resource provider action to export and it exports the whole resource group. just remove all the extra parts.